# Azure Devops can't disable "New service connections experience"

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to disable the **Preview features** *New service connections experience*. But the switch button stays gray with all roles.

[image]

It's actually impossible to disable it ? I'm having trouble to set the ssh connection for this [Copy Files Over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops), and many issues ask to disable that preview feature.

Thanks

Comment: It s probably enabled at the organization level, ask a global admin to check that

Comment: I tried to create a new organization and the switch button is still disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls use "ssh-keygen -m PEM" while generating the ssh keys. I had the same issue, generating key using the above command resolved my issue. For reference:

**What key formats are supported for the SSH tasks?

The Azure Pipelines SSH tasks use the Node.js ssh2 package for SSH connections. Ensure that you are using the latest version of the SSH tasks. Older versions may not support the OpenSSH key format.
If you run into an "Unsupported key format" error, then you may need to add the -m PEM flag to your ssh-keygen command so that the key is in a supported format.**

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops#what-key-formats-are-supported-for-the-ssh-tasks
```